# What kind of (materialized) view suits this situation?

Tags: sql, oracle, view

The view is result of inner joining of three tables with conditions, each holding many thousands records and around 15 columns

Two of the big table(10 thousands records and 100 thousands) get heavy update(`INSERT` or `UPDATE`) could up to `5000 times daily` but in unpredictable frequency.

The front end should show up the current data of the joining result for `every 30 seconds`.

The goal is the best performance with little resource overhead(that's cliche but still, always the requirement)

Here are the questions based on the situation:

1. Is materialized view necessary? What's the performance/resource cost if the only use regular view? If so, is `Refresh on Commit` necessary?
2. If decide to use materialized view, is `prebuilt` necessary to make the query faster and resource cost(memory, CPU) can be reduced?
3. If `Refresh on Commit` materialized view, is `partitioning` necessary base on this amount of data?
4. It seems to create `index` on the view can make query faster, but what is the resource cost on such setting? It is really a pain to see `Out of memory` error and such from Oracle

thanks

Comment: If I join two tables of size N and M, the size of the result set could be anywhere between min(N,M) and N*M. So you haven't really given any information on the size of the result set.

Comment: @popovitsj I thought we should always assume the worst scenario?